# Why is the initial value changing and not the objects value?

Tags: java, object, reference

This is going to be quite long winded as I'm still relatively very new to Java as a language.

This program has a Class called Point. This creates Points for vertices of shapes.

```
    public class Point {

        private int x;
        private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

     }
```

In this class, there are methods such as distance (between 2 points), scale(increases by factor), translate(takes an x and y coordinate and adds it to this.x and x.y) and so on.

I then have 3 more classes to create shapes. Triangle, Rectangle and Circle, where the constructors look like this.

```
    public class Triangle {

        private int sides;
        private Point[] points;

    public Triangle(Point[] vertices) {

        this.sides = 3;
        this.points = vertices;

}
```

.

```
    public class Rectangle {

        private int sides;
        private Point topCorner;
        private int width;
        private int length;



    public Rectangle(Point corner, int w, int l){

        this.sides = 4;
        this.topCorner = corner;
        this.width = w;
        this.length = l;

}
```

and

```
    public class Circle {

        private Point center;
        private int radius;

    public Circle(Point center, int radius){

        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;

}
```

All these classes have the same methods translate, and scale. An example of which is shown here.

```
    //For the Rectangle Class
    public void translate(int dx, int dy){

        topCorner.translate(dx, dy);

}
```

My problem is in my main class. What happens is I created 3 points, and used all 3 as an array to create the triangle, and 2 others as points for the rectangle and for the circle. Now when I call the translate method on all 3 objects in one go, it ends up doubling the value, as I believe my mistake is that I have passed a reference to "p1" "p2" and "p3" somewhere, and I am changing their values instead of the objects values. Here is the code, and I will explain the output after

```
    public class GraphicsDemo {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p1 = new Point(0,20);
    Point p2 = new Point(20,0);
    Point p3 = new Point(30,30);


    Point[] vertices = {p1,p2,p3};

    Triangle t = new Triangle(vertices);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(p1,10,15);
    Circle c = new Circle (p2, 25);


    System.out.println("Triangle" + "\n" + t.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + t.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + t.perimeter());
    System.out.println("Reactangle" + "\n" + r.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + r.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + r.perimeter());
    System.out.println("Circle" + "\n" + c.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + c.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + c.perimeter());

    c.translate(10, 15);
    t.translate(10, 15);
    r.translate(10, 15);

System.out.println("Triangle" + "\n" + t.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + t.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + t.perimeter());
    System.out.println("Reactangle" + "\n" + r.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + r.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + r.perimeter());
    System.out.println("Circle" + "\n" + c.toString() + "\n" + "area:" + c.area() + "\n" + "perimeter: " + c.perimeter());;
```

The output for this is that instead of adding 10 and 15 to a shapes coordinates, 20 and 30 are added if the point is used in more than one shape. I'm sure that this is because I'm actually changing the value of the points instead of the objects, but I have no idea how to change this.

Thank you to anyone that can help in advance. This is the first time in my experience where I have tried a lot of things and am up against a wall.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to show the most important part of your code, however it looks like your analysis is correct. In your translation code you actually need to generate new point instances (and replace them).

This is generally a good idea to not modify objects but keep them immutable. Best way to ensure this is to skip the setters:

```
class Point {
  Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
  int getX() { return x; } intGetY() { return y; }

  /** Create a new point displaced by given coordinates. */
  Point translate(int deltaX, int deltaY) 
  {
    return new Point(this.getX() + deltaX, this.getY() + deltaY);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assumption is correct,  you are passing references.  Circle, Triangle, Rectangle are all taking one or more points in common with the other shapes in their constructor.  See rectangle which takes the same point (p1) as triangle.

```
Point[] vertices = {p1,p2,p3};

Triangle t = new Triangle(vertices);
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(p1,10,15);
Circle c = new Circle (p2, 25);
```

A simple solution is to clone the points in the constructors as I did in the Triangle class below.   This means the two shapes will share the same x and y to start with, but changes to one shape will no longer directly affect the other.

A class is an object reference.  So you need to create a new Object reference to create separate objects to work on.  This is what the .clone() method I added to you point class does, it copies the internals of point and creates an exact copy.  The constructors of the other methods then invoke the clone method on the points you feed them, so that they are only working on copies of the points you give them.

```
class Point{

public int x;
public int y;

Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Point clone(){

    return new Point(x,y);

}
```

}

```
class Triangle{

final static int m_sides = 3;  //constant
Point[] m_points;

Triangle(Point[] points){

    //You need to clone your ponits.
    m_points = new Point[]{
            points[0].clone(), 
            points[1].clone(),
            points[2].clone()};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed the same object. I.e Triangle t has p1. If you change Rectangle p1 you are changing triangle p1 as well.

You should do deep clones in Point's for them to be independent.